# Why am I getting an error on CSP Connect-src allow all?

Tags: security, next.js, content-security-policy

I'm facing a puzzling issue in my NextJs project where a Content Security Policy (CSP) violation is being triggered for the connect-src directive, despite my configuration seemingly allowing all connections. The violation error message I receive is as follows:

> connect-src: csp_violation: 'https://< URL >/api/v2/rest' blocked by
> 'connect-src' directive of the policy "default-src 'self'; script-src
> 'self' 'report-sample'; style-src 'self' 'report-sample'; base-uri
> 's..."

Here is my actual CSP Headers:

```
     default-src 'self' *.url1.com *.url2.dev *.url3.com *.url4.com *.url5.io; 
     style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
     script-src 'self' https://url6.com *.url8.com *.url7.com 'unsafe-eval' 'sha256-<token>=' https://www.url8.com; 
     worker-src blob:; 
     font-src 'self'; 
     frame-src 'self'; 
     media-src 'self'; 
     object-src *; 
     img-src 'self' *.url9.net;
     connect-src *; 
     base-uri 'self';
```

Given this configuration, it's unclear why the request to

> https://< URL>/api/v2/rest

is being blocked, as my connect-src directive explicitly allows all connections with *. I'm considering adding

> connect-src: * https://< URL>/api/v2/rest;

explicitly to the policy. Would this be a correct approach, or are there alternative steps I should consider to resolve this issue? I'm at a bit of a loss on how to proceed and would appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely explanation when the policy in the error message doesn't match the one you have set is that there are multiple CSPs set. All content needs to pass all policies. Check the response headers for other policies and try to identify where/how they are set to be able to modify/disable them. They can be set in code, in web server configuration or in a proxy.